# Pegar os valores de um tabela e usar para criar um novo banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress

Bom estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou mudando de servidor para uma agencia, e me deparei com o seguinte problema: ele possuía apenas 1 banco de dados e dentro desse banco de dados haviam varias tabelas com os nomes dos clientes.

O problema que é que dentro dessas tabelas tinha outras tabelas com o Wordpress por exemplo. Eu gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um backup dessa tabela com as tabelas do Wordpress dentro, e restaurar como um novo Banco de dados dentro do novo servidor.

Comment: Você pode mandar o print da hierarquia, organização dessas tabelas, lá no phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa organização que você descreveu não é a padrão do WordPress. Normalmente quando existem múltiplas instalações do WordPress dentro do mesmo banco de dados, utiliza-se um prefixo para cada instalação. Aí você tem como identificar as tabelas pelo prefixo e exportá-las separadamente.

Se você ainda tem acesso ao WordPress de cada cliente o melhor é usar o próprio exportador do WordPress para mover os sites. Ele vai cuidar do banco de dados e de todos os anexos e você não vai precisar se preocupar com a forma que o banco de dados foi organizado.

Dependendo do tamanho do site e da performance do servidor, a importação pode dar erro de timeout ou de memória. Neste caso você tem duas opções. Ou separa o xml de exportação em pedaços menores ou utiliza um plugin de backup para transferir o banco de dados.

Se for utilizar um plugin de backup, indico o [BackupWordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/). Precisa do PHP maior que 5.3 pra rodar. Faz um backup só do banco de dados que ele vai criar um arquivo sql só com as tabelas relativas àquele site.

Comment: Oi Ricardo, tudo bem? Já consegui resolver o problema, fiz exatamente isso que falou. Consegui resolver o problema tranquilamente.... Obrigado!